# My program keeps outputting "undefined". I am trying to create a function that changes text on my webpage with a button that calls a function

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create a program that takes a user's input from the html and runs it through a for loop, and then displays the translated input. The problem is that the output just displays `undefined`. The function that translates the user's input in the inputbox is supposed to be called with the button in the html, but clicking it changes nothing, and the output just stays "undefined"

```
function whaleTalk() {
  let input = document.getElementById('input').value

  const vowels = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'];

  let resultArray = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {

    for (var j = 0; j < vowels.length; j++) {

      if (input[i] == vowels[j]) {

        if (input[i] == 'e') {
          resultArray.push('ee');


        } else if (input[i] == 'e') {
          resultArray.push('uu');


        } else {
          resultArray.push(input[i]);

        }
      }
    }
  }

  console.log(resultArray.join('').toUpperCase());
  document.getElementById('input').innerHTML = input;
  document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = resultArray.join('').toUpperCase();
  console.log(resultArray);
}

function translateInput() {
  let userInput = document.getElementById('input').value
  let translateResult = whaleTalk(userInput);
  updateOutput(translateResult);
}

function updateOutput(input) {
  document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = input;
}

whaleTalk();
updateOutput();
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>

   <title>Whale Talk Translator</title>

   <meta charset="utf-8">

   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">

   <link href="whaletranslator.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<style>



</style>

</head>



<body>

   <header style="color: white;">Whale Talk Translator </header>

<h2>Input anything you want into the box below and hit the button to translate it.</h1>

   <div class="translatorBox">

      <input value="" id="input" type="text" class="inputBox" placeholder="Text to translate">

      <br>

      <div class="container">
         <div class="center">
            <button class="translateButton" onclick="updateOutput()">Translate</button>
         </div>
       </div>
      
      <div class="container">
         <div class="center">
            <button class="reloadButton" onClick="window.location.reload();">Reload</button>
         </div>
       </div>

   </div>

 
   <p style="padding: 2em">Translated input:</p>
   <div class="output">
       <p id="output"></p>

</body>
<script src="whaletranslator.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: Any JS function that does not explicitly `return` something returns the default return value, which is `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

Your function returns undefined because you are not returning anything from it. Try this:

```
function whaleTalk() {
  let input = document.getElementById('input').value

  const vowels = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'];

  let resultArray = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {

    for (var j = 0; j < vowels.length; j++) {

      if (input[i] == vowels[j]) {

        if (input[i] == 'e') {
          resultArray.push('ee');


        } else if (input[i] == 'e') {
          resultArray.push('uu');


        } else {
          resultArray.push(input[i]);

        }
      }
    }
  }
  
  return resultsArray.join('').toUpperCase()
}
```

Now when your `translationResult` variable will be the string that your `updateOutput` method will set to the innerHtml of the element with id 'output'. Instead of calling the two methods at the bottom you can now just call `translateInput()`

Answer (score -1):

You haven't satisfied the argument for the method `updateOutput`, the "undefined" message is caused because the argument is not defined in your call

Comment: Wrong. The reason is that the function doesn't explicitly return anything.

Comment: @connexo Yea that's the error, I haven't read the other code

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).